# Multiple parameter packs of different types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost

Okay so what I have is as follows:

```
template< int... ints, class... classes >
magic_return_type<ints..., classes...> func() { \* snip *\ }

template< int... ints, class... classes >
class obj
{
public:
   obj() : x(func<ints, classes>()) {}
private:
   magic_return_type<ints..., classes...> x;
};
```

Apparently clang++ and g++ let `func` get away with having multiple parameter packs, but `obj` cannot, because I receive the following error:

```
error: parameter pack 'ints' must be at the end of the template parameter list
```

For this problem you can assume that `magic_return_type` exists, and is "logically correct".  (it ends up being a `boost::fusion::vector` of some stuff in the non-toy version).

The possible solutions/workarounds that I see:

- Find some magical way I don't know about to have it do what I want.
- Pass `boost::mpl` objects to `obj` instead of parameter packs, which solves `obj`'s problem, but I don't know how to convert them to parameter-packs for `func`.
- Pass `boost::mpl` objects to both `obj` and `func` which I don't really mind doing, but I feel like it's changing upstream to fix a downstream problem, so I thought I'd check on SO to see if people could come up with something smarter.

Any ideas guys?  Is option #3 the only way to go?

Cheers!

Comment: The function template declaration is ill-formed. [temp.param]/11 contains a similar example: `template<class... T, class... U> void f() { } // error`. "A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed
by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the *parameter-type-list*
of the function template or has a default argument."

Comment: I'm sorry, that's an artifact of this being a toy problem (not sure why gcc and clang still let it go, but that might be a bug with them).  In the real problem, "classes" is a parameter for func, so that pack can be deduced.

EDIT:  Also, that's a different situation...two packs of classes.  This is a pack of ints and a pack of classes.

Comment: It's interesting though that both g++4.8.2 and clang++3.5 accept that function template declaration without issuing any diagnostic.

Comment: Option 4: `template<class... ints> class o { template<class... classes> class bj { /*...*/ }; }; o<1,2,3>::bj<int,void> x;` But I think the tuple/mpl approach is simpler: `obj<int_seq<1,2,3>, tuple<int,void>>`, which can even be simplified to `obj<int_seq<1,2,3>, int, void>`.

Comment: Option 5: Use type `std::integral_constant<int, value>` instead of `int`.

Comment: @dyp Hmm, in my real problem `classes` is deduce-able so I was planning on already having a `make` function for it (similar to how `boost::make_optional` is used to avoid template parameter messiness.)  Given this, option 4 doesn't seem like too bad of an idea.

Comment: @Jarod42 Then, how do you separate the integers from types?

Comment: @dyp: Yes there is (a lot of) extra work to do that (I don't think my option is really good here, but it is an option).

Comment: @dyp It looks like your solution will be the one that I go with due to the specifics of my situation--specifically that it was already very useful to have a helper generation function, and to hide the type behind `auto`, so the "messy" type name doesn't come into play very much.

If you write that up as an actual answer, there's a good chance I'll accept it.